# Custom layout with Slick Carousel

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slick.js

I am currently using slick carousel.  At the moment, I have a very simple layout

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="imageSlide">
          <div><img src="http://www.atfund.gatech.edu/sites/default/files/images/verticalplaceholderimage-440x680.png" class=""></div>
          <div><img src="http://www.atfund.gatech.edu/sites/default/files/images/verticalplaceholderimage-440x680.png" class=""></div>
          <div><img src="http://www.atfund.gatech.edu/sites/default/files/images/verticalplaceholderimage-440x680.png" class=""></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I have it set up to use center mode

```
$('.imageSlide').slick({
    infinite: true,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '60px',
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

That produces the expected result as seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z69w9u4g/6/)

The problem I am having is customising this.  I am after a layout like the following
[image]

So I am looking to have the main image as the focus, with an additional 2 image displayed to its right with a lower opacity.  When you click the nav, the focus image will disappear, and the next image becomes the focus.  Nothing should display to the left of the focused image, but always two to the right.

I have searched high and low for a plugin that can do this, but nothing is this specific.

Is it possible to achieve in slick, or is there some other way I can achieve this effect?

Thanks

Comment: Try changing the slidesToShow option from 1 to 3.

Comment: I had previously done that, but it seems to place them all together and if there are only 3 images, it doesnt slide

Comment: To keep them from sticking together, you may just need to change width of the image. 

You can pass the value dynamically. So count how many images you have, if more than 3, set the slidesToShow value to 3, if it's 3 or less, set it to 1.